# How to solve Execution failed for task ':generateReleaseBuildConfig'. error in a flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, apk

I am running `flutter build apk` command in my flutter project and receiving the error below

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateReleaseBuildConfig'.
> Error while evaluating property 'applicationId' of task ':generateReleaseBuildConfig'
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateReleaseBuildConfig' property 'applicationId'.
      > Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
         > Manifest file does not exist: C:\Repos\yousafe\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            9.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

However the AndroidManifest.XML file exists at the said location in the Android\app\src\main directory and there's nothing wrong with it;

I could also share the settings.gradle and the build.gradle files but I am sure there's nothing wrong with them.

I ran Flutter Doctor and this was the output;

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22635.3350], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.5)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

and this one issues is because I prefer to use VsCode to Android Studio so I uninstalled it. Everything seems to checkout. I would appreciate any pointers on to what exactly I am missing.

Comment: in a standard flutter project the path of the manifest file is the following: 

flutter_project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

you structure seems not be be a proper one for a flutter project.  Did you setup the project from scratch via the flutter CLI?

Comment: Hello @AndroDevs yes the project was setup  the standard way; only a few tweaks were made to the MinSDK version because of a requirement of one of the packages